# Четверостишие с последней короткой строкой.

Tags: стихи

Здравствуйте. Последнее время в Интернете распространилась мода (хотя встречал и у классиков) на четверостишия с рифмой АБАБ и с сокращённой (чаще всего односложной) последней строкой.

бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла

бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла

бла-бла-бла-бла-бла-бла

бла-бла

Не подскажета как называется такая форма стихосложения?

p.s. Знаю, что для двустишия это называется эхо-рифма. Но всё же это немножко не то.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, как у классиков, а сейчас такая форма называется "порошок".

Бодлер жевал цветы полыни
был мрачен зол и декадент
он получал в прямом отжиме
абсент

Comment: А отсутствие знаков препинания тоже признак совремнного стихотворения?

Comment: Зря иронизируете, это действительно один из канонов порошкового жанра)

Comment: Кто декадент? Ничего не понять.